# Forward Flex Gateway Logs to Splunk

Tags: splunk, mulesoft, fluent-bit, anypoint-platform

I have an instance of MuleSoft's Flex Gateway (v 1.2.0) installed on a Linux machine in a podman container. I am trying to forward container as well as API logs to Splunk. Below is my log.yaml file in /home/username/app folder. Not sure what I am doing wrong, but the logs are not getting forwarded to Splunk.

```
apiVersion: gateway.mulesoft.com/v1alpha1
kind: Configuration
metadata:
  name: logging-config
spec:
  logging:
    outputs:
    - name: default
      type: splunk
      parameters:
        host: <instance-name>.splunkcloud.com
        port: "443"
        splunk_token: xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx
    tls: "on"
    tls.verify: "off"
    splunk_send_raw: "on"
    runtimeLogs:
      logLevel: info
      outputs: 
      - default
    accessLogs:
      outputs:
      - default
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint for Splunk's HTTP Event Collector (HEC) is `https://http-input.<instance-name>.splunkcloud.com:443/services/collector/raw`.  If you're using a free trial of Splunk Cloud then change the port number to 8088.  See https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Data/UsetheHTTPEventCollector#Send_data_to_HTTP_Event_Collector_on_Splunk_Cloud_Platform for details.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I'm not using a free trial of Splunk.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this work. The issue was that I had to give full permissions to the app folder using "chmod" command. After it was done, the fluent-bit.conf file had an entry for Splunk and logs started flowing.